# Can you help me making heroku's spring/MVC example work?

Tags: spring-mvc, heroku, spring-roo

I am trying to perform this tutorial:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate#prerequisites

I was able to follow all the steps without problems, but when I run mvn package, I get this outputs:
(I will store the file in paste.bin so it the message is cleaner. If you wish the files and outputs here, let me know in the comments and I will edit)
[For this POM.xml](http://pastebin.com/FEzDbXwf)
I get [This output with errors](http://pastebin.com/3SzVTMnh)

It seems that maven can't resolve org.springframework.roo but it is listed in the dependencies, this should be enough, correct? This is my first time with spring and maven, I would like to test its integration with heroku, but I got stuck on this one.

ps: I donwloaded STS from eclipse marketstore. My current thought is that it doesn't install roo, now I am verifying this.

Did anyone made this tutorial work?

thanks!

EDIT: Theoretically I would not need to install Roo if I cloned a git repo with the application template. That was what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have marked the spring roo package as being provided.  This means that it is not available during compile time and is not included in the final package but will be available during run time. Should this be the case? If not try removing the provided scope  `<scope>provided</scope>` and see if that fixes it.

```
    <!-- ROO dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${roo.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I removed this tag but it didn't work. I realized that maybe the Java world is not my thing, I will look for technologies alternatives. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah thats too bad, I wouldn't give up that easily.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but this is my spare time project, I'd rather spend time building the project than configuring the framework itself :(